# how to group mongodb documents in php

Tags: php, mongodb, grouping

I am using mongo server 3.6 and php as backend language.
Also I am using the latest php-mongo library to talk to new updated drivers.

I have a collection with 10 million records in it like so :

```
[
  {
    "did": "123456",
    "did_usage": "1",
    "did_timestamp": "15012"
  },
  {
    "did": "4567811",
    "did_usage": "1",
    "did_timestamp": "15013"
  },
  {
    "did": "46465464",
    "did_usage": "2",
    "did_timestamp": "15014"
  },
  {
    "did": "7894446",
    "did_usage": "2",
    "did_timestamp": "15015"
  },
  {
    "did": "65646131",
    "did_usage": "3",
    "did_timestamp": "15016"
  },
  {
    "did": "7989464",
    "did_usage": "2",
    "did_timestamp": "15017"
  },
  {
    "did": "651651664",
    "did_usage": "1",
    "did_timestamp": "15018"
  }.......
]
```

Now I want to find a single unique document which have least did usage and least did timestamp.

Till now I have reached to find the single unique document using :

```
$sample = array('$sample' => array('size' => 1));
$pipeline = array($match, $group, $project, $sample);
$cursor = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

I want some help regarding the `$group`.
I have tried this

```
$group = array('$group' => array('_id' => '$did_usage', 'did_usage_timestamp' => array('$min' => '$did_usage_timestamp')));
```

But this is not working as expected.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without knowing what `$match` and `$project` are doing in your original code, we can assume that `$group` is operating on a subset of the collection data since it is only preceded by `$match` in the pipeline. Based on only the example collection data and the `$group` stage, it's evident that the `$dig_usage_timestamp` [field path](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables) used with the `$min` operator references a non-existent field in the documents entering the `$group` stage.

When testing this locally, `did_usage_timestamp` in the randomly selected output document is `null`:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client;
$collection = $client->test->foo;

$collection->drop();
$collection->insertMany([
    ["did" => "123456", "did_usage" => "1", "did_timestamp" => "15012"],
    ["did" => "4567811", "did_usage" => "1", "did_timestamp" => "15013"],
    ["did" => "46465464", "did_usage" => "2", "did_timestamp" => "15014"],
    ["did" => "7894446", "did_usage" => "2", "did_timestamp" => "15015"],
    ["did" => "65646131", "did_usage" => "3", "did_timestamp" => "15016"],
    ["did" => "7989464", "did_usage" => "2", "did_timestamp" => "15017"],
]);

$cursor = $collection->aggregate([
    ['$group' => ['_id' => '$did_usage', 'did_timestamp' => ['$min' => '$did_usage_timestamp']]],
    ['$sample' => ['size' => 1]],
]);

var_dump($cursor->toArray());
```

This outputs something similar to:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#14 (1) {
    ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
    array(2) {
      ["_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["did_timestamp"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Changing the `$min` operator's field path to `$did_timestamp` should resolve the issue.